# Using matter-js when adding a Body using fromVertices - the resulting vertices are not positioned correctly with relation to each other

Tags: javascript, 2d, vertices, matter.js

Here's the shape I'm expecting to see.  You can see the points along the edge depicting the vertices.

[image: cannon depicting vertices]

Here's the json file (generated from the above) that I'm loading in (via a simple import) and using to create the `Body`.

```
{
    "cannon_transparent_sm": {
        "label": "cannon",
        "density": 0.1,
        "restitution": 0,
        "friction": 0.1,
        "frictionAir": 0.01,
        "frictionStatic": 0.5,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "label": "cannon_fixture",
                "vertices": [
                    [ { "x":150, "y":45 }, { "x":134, "y":0 }, { "x":18, "y":30 }, { "x":1, "y":56 }, { "x":21, "y":94 }, { "x":86, "y":76 } ],
                    [ { "x":43, "y":17 }, { "x":44, "y":23 }, { "x":59, "y":19 }, { "x":58, "y":14 } ],
                    [ { "x":6, "y":41 }, { "x":1, "y":56 }, { "x":18, "y":30 } ],
                    [ { "x":6, "y":83 }, { "x":21, "y":94 }, { "x":1, "y":56 }, { "x":2, "y":72 } ],
                    [ { "x":86, "y":76 }, { "x":21, "y":94 }, { "x":25, "y":108 }, { "x":48, "y":124 }, { "x":61, "y":124 }, { "x":73, "y":119 }, { "x":83, "y":109 }, { "x":88, "y":95 } ],
                    [ { "x":34, "y":118 }, { "x":48, "y":124 }, { "x":25, "y":108 } ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The above was generated from this [physicseditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) tool.

There's a problem when I try to add this to my 2d world.  I'm using the javascript library [matter-js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) and [fromVertices()](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_fromVertices) to generate the sprite.

This is what I see however.

[image: actual]

It looks to me like each set of vertices has been positioned incorrectly with relation to each other.

Here's the javascript I'm using to add the "cannon".

```
var cannonBodyDef = {
  position: Vector.create(300, 50),
  density: this._cannon.density,
  restitution: this._cannon.restitution,
  friction: this._cannon.friction,
  frictionStatic: this._cannon.frictionStatic,
  frictionAir: 0.9, //this._cannon.frictionAir
};

var cannon = Bodies.fromVertices(300, 200, this._cannon.fixtures[0].vertices, cannonBodyDef);

World.add(engine.world, cannon);
```

It's also dropping to the floor (expected) then wobbling a little and falling straight through!  Even though the floor is `static: true`.  Not sure if that is related.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Matter slices off the protruding parts of your shape, making it convex. I would suggest using poly-decomp library to decompose your concave shape into the set of convexes. And when creating a body from vertices, you'll have to sort the flatted array, which you export from physics editor.

```
Common.setDecomp(require('poly-decomp'))
const cannon = Bodies.fromVertices(x, y, [Vertices.clockwiseSort(vertices.flat())])
```

Got something like this, might look better with some overlapping texture:

[image]